# hibernate 4.1.3 manual flush not working

Tags: hibernate

I have the following code which does not do a entityManager.flush() call..

https://github.com/deanhiller/Hibernate-example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/javatpoint/mypackage/StoreData.java

but for some reason, my changes are being flushed out on entityManager.persist(user) for BOTH inserting company and user.  It seems like the persist internally is calling flush.  That just doesn't seem right.

I wrote this whole simple example project as I am debugging why play1.3 is not working with this version of hibernate too...

https://github.com/deanhiller/Hibernate-example

It is very easy to install by just running ./gradlew eclipse

I also have log4jdbc installed so I can see the insert statements happeneing at the persist time which I find very odd.  Any ideas what is going on here?

Ideally, if nothing is flushed in manual mode, a commit will do nothing but my changes are being saved to the database which I find weird.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I had to use GenerationType.SEQUENCE and not AUTO and AUTO must be picking a bad mode or soemthign as it would flush on persiste.  Changing the sequence generator fixed this issue and is demonstrated in that above project now as it currently works fine.